# Reveal a picture covered with a solid color

Tags: silverlight, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to build an application that reveals a picture covered initially with a solid color(black). The idea is that when I click somewhere on that black screen (initially) a circular area around the black pixel I clicked to be made transparent so I can see the image behind.

The solution that I came up with is to use a canvas with the picture I want covered set as background. The black cover will be divided in pixels (stored on a matrix perhaps - the image will be maximum 500x500). All those pixels will be colored black initially and then, knowing the pixel the user clicks make transparent (or delete) all pixels around that one until I clear a circular area with a preset diameter.

I don't have much experience with canvases and this solution seems quite rough to me. I wanted ask a second opinion, or if someone can give me a better solution

I'm developing the app in Silverlight, if that's relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes! I'd say it's very relevant that you are developing in Silverlight. XAML has some very powerful image manipulation capabilities. You can use an opacity mask to specify what part of the picture you wish to show. Also, silverlight is able to use your GPU, you do need to specify this explicitly.

Comment: Just make a really large png with a cutout circle in the center. Overlay this png over the other image but make sure to position the cutout outside of the viewport. Then on click, move the png cutout cirlce to the place where the user clicked. All you have to do is calculate the position of the cutout to the location of the click... Or if you're interested in revealing more and more portions of the image then use flup's suggestion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx

Comment: I found an example: http://silverscratch.blogspot.nl/2010/03/animating-silverlight-opacity-mask.html In particular the burn code, I'd think. You'd like to do the reverse of the burn and let it be steered by the user, instead of computations.

Comment: thank you all for your responses. @DeviantSeev I forgot to mention that the user can click multiple times on the image to reveal many areas (that may intersect). Flup: I'll look into opacity masks to see what can I do with them. Thank you very much!

Comment: Am getting slightly less enthusiastic about the example. Looked into the code and the animations are all predefined in the .xaml files. So not quite sure how easy or hard it is to change the opacity mask programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I spend reading about silverlight controls I ended up using Image.Clip. Here's an example in case somebody like me needs it:

```
  <Image Source="Images/img.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="19">                                                
            <Image.Clip>
                <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="100,100"></EllipseGeometry>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="80,100"></EllipseGeometry>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="80,83"></EllipseGeometry>                        
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="60,60"></EllipseGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
```

Of course, ellipses can be placed programmatic.